VSCode opens my venv, directory and preferred terminal (Git Bash) but directory is incorrect
I have configured VSCode to activate my venv, use Git Bash as preferred terminal, and have the workspace for my repo, the only issue is that the directory looks like it's incorrect, however, after using pwd, I verify the repo is correct. The correct directory should be /c/Users/User/OneDrive/Documents/Python/house_predictions.
(venv) 
User@DESKTOP-4D34S12 MINGW64 C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code (feature/web-scraper)
$ pwd
/c/Users/User/OneDrive/Documents/Python/house_predictions
(venv) 
User@DESKTOP-4D34S12 MINGW64 C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code (feature/web-scraper)
$ cd reports
(venv) 
User@DESKTOP-4D34S12 MINGW64 /c/Users/User/OneDrive/Documents/Python/house_predictions/reports (feature/web-scraper)
$ cd ..
(venv) 
User@DESKTOP-4D34S12 MINGW64 /c/Users/User/OneDrive/Documents/Python/house_predictions (feature/web-scraper)

I've tried messing with input to the .bashrc file:
# Set the default working directory
cd /c/Users/User/OneDrive/Documents/Python/house_predictions

I've also tried messing with the house_predictions.code-workspace.json file:
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": ".."
        }
    ],
    "settings": {
        "python.terminal.activateEnvInCurrentTerminal": true,
        "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
        "terminal.integrated.cwd": "C:\\Users\\User\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Python\\house_predictions",
        "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Git Bash",
        "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
            "Git Bash": {
                "path": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
                "icon": "terminal-bash"
            }
        }
    }
}

